# Java with some build error

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee

[image]
I am getting the below error "Description Resource Path Location Type The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement. Fix the build path then try building this project cucumber Unknown Java Problem
I have pasted the error below in the comments.
Below is my pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.bdd</groupId>
  <artifactId>cucumber</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>cucumber</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <configuration>
           <source>1.7</source>
           <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
  </plugin>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pom file is not proper.It should be like below

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>3.0</version>
             <configuration>
                  <source>1.7</source>
                  <target>1.7</target>
             </configuration>               
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Description Resource Path Location Type The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement.

Looks like your build-path is messed up somehow. Right-click on the project and goto *properties* --> *configure build-path)*. You will be able to pin-point the issues in the build path from there.

Make sure that everything is configured and referenced properly from the project and that the JDK(not jre) is also setup correctly.

Comment: Below are the errors in console - Description Resource Path Location Type
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement. Fix the build path then try building this project cucumber  Unknown Java Problem

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
The type java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files CukesRunner.java /cucumber/src/test/java/com/bdd/cucumber line 1 Java Problem

Comment: It means that a class that you use, needs another class that is not on the classpath. Make sure to add all required libraries on your class-path. Go through the `referenced-libraries` one by one and see what is missing